# How the IdentityServer processes the token request?

Tags: .net, authentication, authorization, grpc, identityserver4

How the IdentityServer processes the request and generates the token?

Does it process only if its http request or it converts it internally if we make request using gRPC? Will there be an issue if we follow the gRPC instead of the http requests?

I am new to this and trying to understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

identityServer follows the OpenID-Connect/OAuth2 standards, and because of that it only supports requests over HTTPS. gRPC is not suitable for authenticating user requests.

gRPC is also not really well supported in the browser (besides gRPC Web), gRPC is more for machine-to-machine communication.

However, once you have received your tokens, you can include the access token in gRPC requests to other services.